# Birch Reduction of Benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction

According to my Organic Chemistry Textbook:

> Benzene can be reduced to 1,4-cyclohexadiene by treating it with an alkali metal (sodium, lithium, or potassium) in a mixture of liquid ammonia and an alcohol. This reaction is called the Birch reduction.
>
> [image]

Why the conjugated 1,3-cyclohexadiene is not formed in this reaction (as conjugated molecules are more stable)?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35621/why-does-the-birch-reaction-not-yield-fully-saturated-products

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48545/mechanism-in-birch-reduction https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61545/birch-reduction-of-anthracene

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the article on Birch Reduction on the Organic Chemistry portal:

The question of why the 1,3-diene is not formed, even though it would be more stable through conjugation, can be rationalized with a simple mnemonic. When viewed in valence bond terms, electron-electron repulsions in the radical anion will preferentially have the nonbonding electrons separated as much as possible, in a 1,4-relationship.

http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/birch-reduction.shtm